# Error when trying to use Power BI REST API - Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: rest, powershell, powerbi

Lately I've been trying to use **Power BI REST API to make the refresh** of a certain dataset automatically, **by calling a .ps1 program**. By following [this](https://www.fourmoo.com/2018/06/05/using-the-power-bi-api-with-powershell-scripts-refreshing-your-dataset/) tutorial, I was able to get [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/manageRefresh.ps1) code, which is addapted as you can see below:

```
$groupID = "me" # the ID of the group that hosts the dataset. Use "me" if this is your My Workspace
$datasetID = "MYDATASETID" # the ID of the dataset that hosts the dataset

$clientId = "MYCLIENTID" 

# Calls the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) to authenticate against AAD
function GetAuthToken
{
       if(-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
         Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
       }

       $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

       $resourceAppIdURI = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"

       $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize";

       $authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority

       $authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $clientId, $redirectUri, "Auto")

       return $authResult
}

$token = GetAuthToken

$authHeader = @{
   'Content-Type'='application/json'
   'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
}

$groupsPath = ""
if ($groupID -eq "me") {
    $groupsPath = "myorg"
} else {
    $groupsPath = "myorg/groups/$groupID"
}

$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$datasetID/refreshes" 
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method POST –Verbose

$uri = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/$groupsPath/datasets/$datasetID/refreshes"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method GET –Verbose
```

I made sure to collect the parameters (`groupID`, `clientID` and `datasetID`) exactly as specified in the links above. However, **when I try to execute this code, I get back the error:**

```
Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'â€Headers System.Collections.Hashtable â€Method'.
At C:\Users\me\Desktop:41 char:1
```

I can't quite tell what's going on, and I even found [some similar cases](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/issues/5), but none of the solutions worked for me. So, some help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Looks to me that the minus signs for `-Header` and `-Method` aren't really normal minus signs. Could come from copying off a webpage. Try and replace those and type them in yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this solution is copy/pasted from somewhere and the dashes are screwed up:

[image]

Delete the last 3 dashes in `Invoke-RestMethod`, which looks like dashes, but are other looks like dash unicode symbols, and replace them with normal "typed by the keyboard" ones.

Hope this helps!